# Synchronized block vs. synchronized method qualifier in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

The following code

```
public class Coordination {

    private  volatile int counter =  0;

    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
        new Coordination().volatileWithCoordination();
    }

    public synchronized void inc() {
        counter++;
    }

    public void volatileWithCoordination() throws Exception {

        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int k = 0; k < 10_000_000; k++) {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        //inc();
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }});

        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int k = 0; k < 10_000_000; k++) {
                    //synchronized(this) {
                    inc();
                    //counter++;
                    //}
                }

            }});

        th1.start();
        th2.start();

        th1.join();
        th2.join();
        System.out.println("counter: "+counter);
    }
}
```

exhibits incorrect and non-deterministic result of `counter: 18025867` whereas switching to:

```
            inc();
        //counter++;
```

in the Runnable of the first thread (`th1`) gives the expected output:

```
counter: 20000000
```

What's causing this `lost update` behavior and why would a synchronized method in this case behave differently to a synchronized(this) block?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The blocks synchronize on the 2 separate thread instances, but the method synchronizes on the same Coordinate instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both threads need to acquire a monitor on the same object, the following change (on either of the 2 threads or both) fixes the situation:

```
synchronized(Coordination.this) {
                    inc();
                //counter++;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your threads are synchronizing on different objects.  Your `th2` thread calls the synchronized `inc()` method, which synchronizes on an instance of the `Coordination` class; but when your th1 thread does `synchronized(this)`, the `this` keyword refers to an instance of the anonymous inner `Runnable` class, not to the `Coordination` class.